# Python Flask WTForm SelectField with Enum values 'Not a valid choice' upon validation

Tags: python, flask, enums, wtforms

My Python Flask app is using WTForms with built in python Enum support. I'm attempting to submit a form (POST) where a SelectField is populated by all values of a Enum.

When I hit 'Submit' i'm given the error, 'Not a valid choice.' This seems strange because when checking the values of the incoming form, the form seemingly does contain a valid choice from the list of Enum values provided.

I'm using a subclass of Enum named `AJBEnum` which is formatted like so:

```
class UserRole(AJBEnum):
    admin = 0
    recipient = 1
```

I chose to do this because I use many Enums through the project and wanted to write a helper function that gathers all choices and formats them WTForm SelectField tuple friendly. AJBEnum is formatted like so:

```
class AJBEnum(Enum):

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls, blank=True):
        choices = []
        if blank == True:
            choices += [("", "")]
        choices += [(choice, choice.desc()) for choice in cls]
        return choices
```

Which means I can give WTForms all choices for `UserRole` during the creating of the SelectField like so:

```
role = SelectField('Role', choices=UserRole.choices(blank=False), default=UserRole.recipient)
```

*Note* the function parameter `blank` provides an additional blank SelectField option in case the SelectField is optional. In this case, it is not.

When I hit the Submit button I check the incoming incoming request in my routes and by printing the `form.data` i'm given this content:

```
{'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'password': 'fake', 'plan': 'A', 'confirm': 'fake', 'submit': True, 'id': None, 'role': 'UserRole.recipient'}
```

As you can see, it appears WTForms has stringified UserRole.recipient. Is there a way to coerce WTForms into converting the incoming POST request value back to the Enum value that it was intended to be?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to coerce WTForms

The argument you're looking for is actually called `coerce`, and it accepts a callable that converts the string representation of the field to the choice's value.

1. The choice value should be an `Enum` instance
2. The field value should be `str(Enum.value)`
3. The field text should be `Enum.name`

To accomplish this, I've extended `Enum` with some `WTForms` helpers:

```
class FormEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(choice, choice.name) for choice in cls]

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, item):
        return cls(int(item)) if not isinstance(item, cls) else item

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class UserRole(FormEnum):
    Owner = 1
    Contributor = 2
    Guest = 3
```

You can then edit a `FormEnum` derived value using a `SelectField`:

```
role = SelectField(
        "Role",
        choices = UserRole.choices(),
        coerce = UserRole.coerce)
```

Comment: Where did you extend Enum? If I understand correctly, you added the helpers to the specific enum (`class UserRole(AJBEnum):`, correct?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example UserRole implementation. The intent is to use `FormEnum` where you'd normally use `Enum`, but otherwise leave your classes unmodified.